# Problems with checking dataGrid values if it's true then update it else add new row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new in WPF and I'm really facing many problems with binding and itemsource and start to haiting this ridiculous way to binding controls especially with dataGrid I'm actually used to programming with winforms,anyway I have a textBox taken Item ID and check it with dataGrid Rows if there is one of its' rows have a same ID then updating its column depending on values i already gave it in other textBoxes like txtQty and txtBuyPrice,and if there is no row with the same ID then just adding new row like the below codes

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemID != "" && txtQty.Text != "" && int.Parse(txtQty.Text) > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Items.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (int.Parse(ItemID) == int.Parse((dataGridView.Items[i] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString()))
                    {
                        (dataGridView.SelectedCells[3].Column.GetCellContent(i) as TextBlock).Text = int.Parse(txtQty.Text) +
                        int.Parse((dataGridView.SelectedCells[3].Column.GetCellContent(i) as TextBlock).Text).ToString();
                        (dataGridView.SelectedCells[4].Column.GetCellContent(i) as TextBlock).Text = txtBuyPrice.Text;
                        (dataGridView.SelectedCells[5].Column.GetCellContent(i) as TextBlock).Text = string.Format("{0:n2}",
                         double.Parse((dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(i) as TextBlock).Text) *
                         double.Parse((dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(i) as TextBlock).Text));                                                     

                        txtSearch.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                }

            object date;
            if (dtpExpireDate.IsEnabled == true)
                date = dtpExpireDate.Text;
            else
                date = null;

            var data = new AddItems { ID = ItemID, ItemName = txtItemName.Text,Date=date,
                                      Qty=txtQty.Text,BuyPrice=txtBuyPrice.Text,
                                      TotalPrice=string.Format("{0:n2}",(int.Parse(txtQty.Text)*double.Parse(txtBuyPrice.Text)).ToString())};

            dataGridView.Items.Add(data);
            ClearItem();

            txtSearch.Focus();
        }
    }
```

reference data come from below function

```
public class AddItems
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public object Date { get; set; }
        public string Qty { get; set; }
        public string BuyPrice { get; set; }
        public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

the exception come when the If condition compare between ItemID and dataGrid rows and also when dataGrid not empty and have already one row beside if dataGrid is empty the new row will added normally and the exception is(Object reference not set to an instance of an object) and this exception pointing to second if statement which it's compare between ItemID and dataGrid Value.
so please I'm already spent 20 hours to get the solve but no really good answer i got.

Comment: WPF is a great way to develop but you have to work with MVVM to achieve maximum efficiency of Databinding.

Comment: @DimosK I,m really need to develop this project as faster as i can so i don't have a time to learn MVVM ,but if you have a cours or a book please mentioned it

Comment: There is alot to read on the Web. Anyway.
How do you bind the datagrid? Do you have a List?

Comment: @DimosK There is no binding i'm only take values from textboxes and put it in dataGrid by AddItems Class ,i don't know if it's right thing or not cuz  i'm not familiar with binding things and if it's not right what should i do to keep things working write ,i'm really so confused.

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms currently? And what is the full datagrid type name?

Comment: @DimosK i'm using WPF and dataGrid name is dataGridView

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper way but due the lack of time for your project I will try to give you the best I can.

First you have to rewrite the AddItems class as following:

```
public class AddItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string id;
    private string itemName;
    private object date;
    private decimal qty;
    private decimal buyPrice;
    private decimal totalPrice;

    public string ID 
    {
        set
        {
            this.id = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
        get{return this.id;}
    }
    public string ItemName 
    {
        set
        {
            this.itemName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ItemName");
        }
        get{return this.itemName;}
    }
    public object Date 
    {
        set
        {
            this.date = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
        get{return this.date;}
    }
    public decimal Qty 
    {
        set
        {
            this.qty = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Qty");
        }
        get{return this.qty;}
    }
    public decimal BuyPrice 
    {
        set
        {
            this.buyPrice = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("BuyPrice");
        }
        get{return this.buyPrice;}
    }
    public decimal TotalPrice 
    {
        set
        {
            this.totalPrice = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
        }
        get{return this.totalPrice;}
    }

    public void AddQuantity(decimal quantity)
    {
        this.qty = this.qty + quantity;
    }
}
```

Add additional logic in the class to update all columns you need.

In tour main code you can build an `ObservableCollection<AddItems> addItemsList = new ObservableCollection<AddItems>()` collection where you can store your row data.

As soon you have filled your list you can bind the grid as follows:
`dataGridView.ItemSource = addItemsList`;

After that you can run any code, for checking, direct on the list insead of the grid, change the values you want etc. All changes are displayed on the grid with no additional coding.

Comment: I'm doing like what you did sir but nothing happend ,there is no row displayed in dataGrid i think i'm doing it in the wrong way i don't even know what databinding or itemsource approach.

Comment: i'm sure the whole values will be added but it's not displayed in dataGrid so what should i do to make it displayed,beside how i can iterate all this list's values to get a specific value for modifying it e.g i need to know which cell have a same ItemID (ItemID come from what i entered from some textbox) if there is a cell have a same value then update the whole row